# Battleship Attack Method Java

Tags: java

I am well and truly stuck on this method. I need to create an attack method for a ComputerPlayer that chooses a random location and attacks the other player's board. Then, there is an attack method where I have to just attack the other player's board. However, when I run the program and place my guesses on my board (GUI), the dots just appear on the ComputerPlayer's board. I don't know why my methods are wrong though.

```
/**
 * Attack the specified Location loc.  Marks
 *   the attacked Location on the guess board
 *   with a positive number if the enemy Player
 *   controls a ship at the Location attacked;
 *   otherwise, if the enemy Player does not
 *   control a ship at the attacked Location,
 *   guess board is marked with a negative number.
 *
 * If the enemy Player controls a ship at the attacked
 *   Location, the ship must add the Location to its
 *   hits taken.  Then, if the ship has been sunk, it
 *   is removed from the enemy Player's list of ships.
 *
 * Return true if the attack resulted in a ship sinking;
 *   false otherwise.
 *
 * @param enemy
 * @param loc
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean attack(Player enemy, Location loc)
{
    int[][] array = getGuessBoard();
    if(!enemy.hasShipAtLocation(loc))
        array[loc.getRow()][loc.getCol()] = -1;
    else
    {
        array[loc.getRow()][loc.getCol()] = 1;
        enemy.getShip(loc).takeHit(loc);
    }

    if(enemy.getShip(loc).isSunk()) {
        enemy.removeShip(enemy.getShip(loc));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



@Override
public boolean attack(Player enemy, Location loc)
{
    int range = (10 - 0) + 1;
    int r = (int) Math.random() * range;
    int c = (int) Math.random() * range;
    int[][] array = getGuessBoard();

    if(array[r][c] != -1)
    {
        if(!enemy.hasShipAtLocation(loc))
            array[loc.getRow()][loc.getCol()] = -1;

        else
        {
            array[loc.getRow()][loc.getRow()] = 1;
            enemy.getShip(loc).takeHit(loc);
        }

        if(getShip(loc).isSunk())
        {
            enemy.removeShip(enemy.getShip(loc));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

GUI for Game

```
     import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
     import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
     import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.IOException;

public class BattleshipDriver extends Canvas implements MouseListener
{
public static final int WIDTH = 1024, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
private Battleship battleship;
private int x, y, squareSize, len;
private Player p1, p2;
private BufferedImage logo, end;

public BattleshipDriver()
{
    battleship = new Battleship();
    battleship.addPlayer(new HumanPlayer("Mr. Hubbard"));
    battleship.addPlayer(new ComputerPlayer("AlphaBattleship"));

    x = 90;
    y = 200;
    squareSize = 36;
    len = squareSize * 10 - 1;
    p1 = battleship.getPlayer(0);
    p2 = battleship.getPlayer(1);

    // Get Battleship Logo
    try {
        logo = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Logo.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get End Screen
    try {
        end = ImageIO.read(new File("src/End.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    addMouseListener(this);

    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Battleship", this);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    render();
}

private void render()
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();

    // Background
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    if(!battleship.gameOver())
    {
        // Boards
        renderGrid(g, x, y, squareSize);
        renderGuesses(g, p1, x, y, squareSize);
        renderGrid(g, 570, y, squareSize);
        renderGuesses(g, p2, 570, y, squareSize);

        // Names
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString(p1.getName(), x, y + 25 + len);
        g.drawString(p2.getName(), 570, y + 25 + len);
    }
    else
    {
        // End Screen
        g.drawImage(end, 0, 0, this);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, squareSize));
        String winner = battleship.getWinner().getName();
        g.drawString(winner, WIDTH / 2 - (winner.length() * squareSize / 4), HEIGHT / 4);
        g.drawString("Wins!", WIDTH / 2 - ("Wins!".length() * squareSize / 4), HEIGHT / 4 + squareSize);
    }

    // Battleship Logo
    g.drawImage(logo, WIDTH / 2 - 246, 10, this);

    g.dispose();
}

private void renderGrid(Graphics g, int x, int y, int s)
{
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, s / 2));

    // Row Lines
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        g.drawLine(x, y+i*s, x+len, y+i*s);

    // Column Lines
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        g.drawLine(x+i*s, y, x+i*s, y+len);

    // Row Markers
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //marks row coordinates on side
        g.drawString(i + "", x-(int)(s*0.43), y+(int)(s*0.67)+s*i);

    // Column Markers
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)     //marks column coordinates on top
        g.drawString(i + "", x+(int)(s*0.4)+s*i, y-(int)(s*0.2));
}

public void renderGuesses(Graphics g, Player player, int x, int y, int s)
{
    int[][] guessBoard = player.getGuessBoard();
    for(int r = 0; r < guessBoard.length; r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < guessBoard[r].length; c++)
            if(guessBoard[r][c] > 0)    // hit
            {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillOval(c*s+x+(int)(s*0.35), r*s+y+(int)(s*0.35), (int)(s*0.33), (int)(s*0.33));
            }
            else if(guessBoard[r][c] < 0)   // miss
            {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillOval(c*s+x+(int)(s*0.35), r*s+y+(int)(s*0.35), (int)(s*0.33), (int)(s*0.33));
            }
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    int r = e.getY();
    int c = e.getX();

    int len = squareSize * 10 - 1;
    if(r > y && r < y + len && c > x && c < x + len)    // clicked on board
    {
        int row = (r - y) / squareSize;
        int col = (c - x) / squareSize;

        System.out.println(row + ", " + col);

        Location loc = new Location(row, col);
        if(p1.getGuessBoard()[row][col] == 0)
        {
            p1.attack(p2, loc);
            p2.attack(p1, loc);
        }

        battleship.upkeep();
        render();
    }

    System.out.println(r + ", " + c);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new BattleshipDriver();
}
```

}

Comment: Are these methods in different classes? You can't have duplicate method names with the same arguments.

Comment: they are: the first one is in HumanPlayer and the 2nd is in ComputerPlayer

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the dots? What does it represent (the guesses, their ships, etc.) and why shouldn't it be showing up?

Comment: it should represent the guesses but now, they are ALL red, meaning I have hit a ship when they should be white. They come everytime I click the HumanPlayer board. The ComputerPlayer board only shows 1 red dot and then it stops.

Comment: Could you include some of the code to displaying the board?

Comment: it's a GUI that my teacher included, I did not code it, just a heads up.

Comment: what is this `if(p1.getGuessBoard()[row][col] == 0) { p1.attack(p2, loc); p2.attack(p1, loc); }`?

Comment: if the location on the guessBoard is 0, then it's okay to attack